# C# - Winform Timer - Disposing and emptying the timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Fairly new to C# and timers, although I've managed to do some really fun stuff in C#, however I'm not getting the hang of Timers.

**Form1.cs:**

```cs
private int counter;
static System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
public void goTimer()
{
    // Set Counter
    counter = 60;

    // If timer is already enabled, stop it.
    if (timer1.Enabled)
    {
        timer1.Dispose();
        //timer1.Stop() <- also tried

    }

    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
    timer1.Start(); // Timer exists

    txtCountdown.Text = counter.ToString();

}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter--;
    if(counter == 0)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
    txtCountdown.Text = counter.ToString();
}
```

So, what happens is that it seems to work as intended, until you start calling `goTimer();` from e.g. a button press, then it will speed up the (int) `counter` as many times as you pressed it... And after a while the memory will be eaten up.

In this case the users will be able to do call the timer function, as it will remove some objects, clear some data and refresh the session, but also when the timer reaches 0.

Using Winforms, I did **not** add a timer in visual studio (it's only referenced here in Form1.cs).

How do I terminate all timers, and then restart at (int) `counter`?

Comment: Timers should *always* be disposed, whether running or not. The *correct* place to do that is in the form's `Dispose` method, not inside the very method that *starts* the timer.

Comment: In any case the method isn't safe - it modifies the timer each time it's called, adding more and more event handlers, when the only thing it should do is call `Start()`

Answer (score 2):

Using start and stop of the `timer` would be the proper aproach, but generally also the dispose variant will work.

Your memory hole results from the multiplied event handler assignments, you need to move this method to your constructor or some other initialization method:

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
```

If you really want to create a new timer every time, you need to release the event handler before:

```
timer1.Tick -= timer1_Tick;
```

Comment: Timers should *always* be disposed, whether stopped or not

Comment: ```c#
if (timer1.Enabled)
            {
                timer1.Tick -= timer1_Tick;
                timer1.Dispose();
                
            }
``` <br> Seems to do the work!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your are right, unless you want to reuse them as in the provided example

Comment: They still have to be disposed when the form closes. The problem with the code is that it's trying to add a *new* event handler instead of just starting or stopping the timer. `goTimer()` should contain only a call to `.Start()`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as MichaelSander already mentioned, you should put these lines in your `Form1.cs` constructor:

`timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
 timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second`

Secondly, there is no point in disposing your timer if it's meant to be used more than once. Instead of `timer1.Dispose()` you should use `timer1.Stop()` just like you do in your `timer1_Tick` handler. Also there is no point in checking whether the timer is enabled or disabled as  both `timer1.Start()` and `timer1.Stop()` will either turn it on/off respectively or do nothing at all. That means that in your case you can remove this block completely:

`if (timer1.Enabled)
{
    timer1.Dispose();
}`